# VBA macro material organizination

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

```
ACRYLIC 0.04"   WHITE
ACRYLIC 0.04"   WHITE
ACRYLIC 0.04"   WHITE
blue    0.04"   WHITE
ACRYLIC 0.04"   WHITE
ACRYLIC 0.04"   WHITE
blue    0.04"   g
```

I want to create an array that stores only unique material.
for example. The program should step through the list and store in a i X 3 array. i being the row that changes. Im having a hard time preserving the values in an array. I want to take each unique 1 X 3 matrix and store them in the array.

array should hold

```
ACRYLIC 0.04"   WHITE
blue    0.04"   WHITE
blue    0.04"   g
```

Comment: Look into dictionaries and Collections.  Or you could simply copy and paste then use Remove Duplicates. Then you can load that into an array.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: I have some but I don't even know how to set up a multidimensional array where the number of rows is a variable. I want to take an array( ACRYLIC 0.04"   WHITE) then add the next unique array under it (blue, 0.04"   WHITE). The dimension then would be 2*3 then 3*3 and so on. The number of rows must be able to change and I dont know how to define the multidimensional array without errors.

Comment: A good start would be searching for "vba multidimensional array"

Answer (score 0):

IMO the most efficient way is to put the data into an array. Then, loop through the array and add the item to a dictionary if the item does not already exist in the dictionary e.g. If not dictionary.Exists(myItemName) then dictionary.Add myItemName, myItemValue. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx
You can then iterate the dictionary and output the data as you need it.